# Compiling real mode asm (rootkit.arsenal)

Tags: c, assembly, real-mode

Im stuck on compiling the tsr.asm code provided in the book rootkit arsenal.
I installed open watcom on a XP maschine and the first asm listing was compiled well.

When compiling, it throws the error: "multiple starting address found"  (nothing found on google). Can anyone confirm that this code is compilable, and how?

Im thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Show us teh codez and how you're compiling them. :)

Comment: can i post it here? since its sold on amazon

Comment: Can you trim it down to the bare minimum that still produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing some code, there is a particular address where the execution is to begin (the `main` function in C for example), but in your code there are more than one starting address, and it crashes when compiling. But without seeing the code I can't tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I was searching for an answer to this and just figured it out - hopefully it'll help someone else Googling around for an answer.

Since you're using OpenWatcom (I'm using version 1.9), I'll assume that you have tsr.asm in its own OpenWatcom 16-bit DOS COM project.  In the IDE, go to Targets -> Target Options -> Linker Switches.  In the window that appears, select "2. Import, Export and Library Switches" from the drop-down at the top and remove the cstart_t entry under "Library files(,): [libf]".

Recompile, and your TSR COM file should be generated.