# Compiling 16-bit assembly code with open watcom error (multiple starting addresses found)

Tags: assembly, dos, 16-bit, watcom, rootkit

I am trying to compile a 16-bit assembly code snippet from the book rootkit arsenal in open watcom IDE. It gives the error "multiple starting addresses found". Having very limited amount of assembly knowledge i have not been able to sort it out. This is the code:

```
CSEG SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CSEG,DS:CSEG,SS:CSEG
ORG 100H


_here:

JMP _main
JMP _overData

_buffer DB 512 DUP('W')
_terminator DB 'Z'
_index DW 0H
_oldISR DD 0H
_chkISR DD 0h
_overData:


_getBufferAddr:

STI
MOV DX, CS
LEA DI,_buffer
IRET


_hookBIOS:

PUSH AX
PUSH BX

PUSHF 
CALL CS:_oldISR

MOV AH, 01H
PUSHF
CALL CS:_chkISR

CLI
PUSH DS 
PUSH CS
POP DS

jz _hb_Exit 
LEA BX,_buffer
PUSH SI
MOV SI,WORD PTR[_index]
MOV DS:[BX+SI],AL
INC SI
MOV WORD PTR[_index], SI
POP SI


_hb_Exit:

POP DS
POP AX
POP BX

STI
IRET


_install:

LEA DX,_getBufferAddr
MOV CX,CS
MOV DS,CX
MOV AH,25H
MOV AL,187
INT 21H

MOV AH,35H
MOV AL,9H
INT 21H
MOV WORD PTR _oldISR[0],BX
MOV WORD PTR _oldISR[2],ES

MOV AH, 35H
MOV AL,16H
INT 21H
MOV WORD PTR _chkISR[0],BX
MOV WORD PTR _chkISR[2],ES

MOV AH,25H
MOV AL,9H
MOV CX,CS
MOV DS,CX
LEA DX,_hookBIOS
INT 21H

RET

PUBLIC _main


_main:

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP
MOV AX,CS
MOV SS,AX
LEA AX,_localStk
ADD AX,100H

CALL NEAR PTR _install

MOV AH, 31H
MOV AL,0
MOV DX, 200H
INT 21H

POP BP
RET

PUBLIC _localStk
_localStk DB 256 DUP(?)

CSEG ENDS
END _here
```

Kindly, help me out.

Comment: Only a guess, but perhaps when the linker sees a public `_main`, it links in the standard library, which has its own entry point? I don't see any reason to make `_main` (or to use that name at all, to be honest) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but I just figured this out and posted a solution on another StackOverflow question asking a similar question:

[Compiling real mode asm (rootkit.arsenal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426012/compiling-real-mode-asm-rootkit-arsenal/17508080#17508080)

Answer (score 0):

What I do to build .com files with OpenWatcom is to compile the assembly file with wasm and then use wlink.

```
wasm hello.asm
wlink sys dos com file hello.o
```

Here the object file has the extension .o which is what wasm produces on Linux.  In DOS, Windows and OS/2 it'll probably be .obj so adjust the command line as appropriate for your system.

I use .model tiny and .286p at the start and leave out the CSEG and ASSUME lines.  I suppose that doesn't matter though.